# How to set up a streaming video between openCV and Google Web Toolkit?

Tags: networking, gwt, opencv

How can I stream video captures from OpenCV via Web to a GWT Server?

Answer (score 0):

Though you need to capture from OpenCV to a GWT Server, it's not exactly the same.
But the following link will provide you with an idea.

- [Streaming OpenCV Videos Over the Network](http://nashruddin.com/Streaming_OpenCV_Videos_Over_the_Network)

Comment: Maybe it is more powerful to use a UDP socket connection than a TCP/IP. What do you think?

Comment: more important.. how can I convert the cvFormats to workable datatypes for Java?